# Bath tub drain/stopper assembly cross has broken off and I can’t remove assembly

Tags: plumbing-fixture

The cross section has broken off when I tried to remove assembly how do I get it off now?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. We'll need more information to help you; in particular, a picture would really help us.

Answer (score 0):

There are various tricks used to remove the *tub strainer* from the *tub waste shoe*. I have had success with this specialty tool found at plumbing shops, it is usually called a "tub strainer spud wrench":

[image]

I have also been able to remove the strainer by carefully cutting slots into it using a keyhole saw, then using pliers to peel it out and away from the tub shoe.

Be careful not to damage the tub, pressed-steel and cast iron tubs often have some corrosion around the strainer hole.